# to test Angularjs Alerts with protractor

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, protractor

i am new to protractor, i want to test alerts 
this is my controller:

```
testapp.controller('SampleCtl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.age = 10;

    $scope.sub = function(a, b) {
        if(a>b){
            return a - b;
        }
        else{
            alert("please enter as first number is graterthan second number ");
        }
    };
}]);
```

this is my html code:

```
    <form onsubmit=""sub(a,b)>
           <input type="number" name="a" id="a">
           <input type="number" name="b" id="b">
           <input type=""submit>
    </form>
```

if we enter 8,7 success.
if we enter 7,8 failure end gives an alert.
how can we end to end test that alert with protractor.
any one please help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call switchTo().alert() on the protractor-object. This will return a promise which provides an alert-object when fulfilled.

```
driver.switchTo().alert().then(function(alert) {
      return alert.dismiss();
    });
```

Assert the alert.getText()-value to check the message itself.

Documentation: http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.AlertPromise

Comment: thanks Johannes Reuter , how can write to expect code to that alert

Comment: as Johannses said "Assert the alert.getText()-value". Something like `expect(alert.getText()).toEqual('Hello Rajana!');`

Comment: I got an error unexpected alert is open. ow can i handle this.